# Soap API sendEmail Must specify a type attribute

Tags: email, soap-api, c#, send-email

I am trying to send an email using the Soap API but always get the following error:

> Additional information: Must specify a {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type attribute value for the {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}messages element

The Soap API itself works like a charm, I can query and insert objects with no problem.

The code is pretty basic, but here it is:

```
EmailFileAttachment efa = new EmailFileAttachment();
efa.body = File.ReadAllBytes(_outputFile.ToString());
efa.fileName = "Ticket";
efa.inline = false;

var attachements = new EmailFileAttachment[1];
attachements[0] = efa;

var mail = new SingleEmailMessage();
mail.orgWideEmailAddressId = _orgWideEmailAddress;
mail.fileAttachments = attachements;
mail.subject = "Registration Mail";
mail.toAddresses = new[] {member.Email};
mail.htmlBody = "Test";

_sForceRef.sendEmail(new []{mail});
```

I have of course also tried it without the attachment, but no change there.

The code of the sendEmail function from the Web Reference looks as followed:

```
public SendEmailResult[] sendEmail([XmlElementAttribute("messages")] SingleEmailMessage[] messages) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("sendEmail", new object[] {
                    messages});
        return ((SendEmailResult[])(results[0]));
}
```

Additionally, I have found the following [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MHbHIAW) where it is suggested, that I'd need to set the type attribute in the XML whether it's a SingleEmailMessage or a MassEmailMessage - but I have no idea how exactly I could achieve that and did find nothing looking for that.

Other things I've tried are to use `new SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}` instead of just `new []{mail}` and to set the Type attribute of the XmlElementAttribute like so: `XmlElementAttribute("messages", typeof(SingleEmailMessage))`, but to no avail.

Comment: I think you just have to change `new []{mail}` to a typed list. I'm not sure of the syntax but maybe `new List<SingleEmailMessage>{mail}` would work instead?

Comment: @AdrianLarson sendEmail only accepts an array, so I tried `new SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}`, but no change there as well :/